# How to check format 3x15 in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to differentiate string format "dxl123awk" from "3x15".

I have regex for checking letter and number: /^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d]/

How to check is string this format: 3x15 or 3x1,5 ?

Comment: Requirements are not entirely clear but perhaps [`\b\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?x\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?\b`](https://regex101.com/r/GdK8oM/1)?

Comment: const regexIsDimensions = /^\b\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?x\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?\b/ , it works, thanks

Comment: If you're using `^`, you don't need the first `\b`. And if you're trying to match the entire string, you should also replace the second `\b` with `$`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```js
^[0-9]+(?:[.,][0-9]+)?x[0-9]+(?:[.,][0-9]+)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mKrvvb/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[0-9]+` - one or more digits
- `(?:[.,][0-9]+)?` - an optional sequence of a `.`/`,` and one or more digits
- `x` - an `x` char
- `[0-9]+` - one or more digits
- `(?:[.,][0-9]+)?` - an optional sequence of a `.`/`,` and one or more digits
- `$` - end of string.